# Connecting Toslink TORX179L optical receiver directly to S/PDIF coaxial input

Tags: toslink, spdif

My goal is to convert optical audio signal - Toslink - to S/PDIF coaxial input signal. The frequency is up to 96 KHz. I'm thinking about Toshiba TORX179L optical receiver. According to the [datasheet](https://www.xsistema.lt/file-manager/downloads/a0dd5ddb-ea43-4cf3-8f16-c4363c19ada9), the output of TORX179L is 0,2V low, and 4V high level voltage. My question is - do I have to use some repeater like 74HCU04 here:
[image]

Or can I directly connect TORX179L to S/PDIF coaxial input? The circuit will be built inside the player.

Comment: What do you mean with "S/PDIF input"?

Comment: I mean S/PDIF RCA coaxial input socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematic shows a TORX173/176 which is confusing.

It also makes it look like the TORX modules have more than 3 pins yet these modules have only 3 pins: vdd, data and gnd, also confusing !

I believe the TORX modules already have some inverter like circuits build-in so adding inverters (the 74HCU04) seems somewhat pointless to me.

I build such a thing once, I did **not** include the inverters but I did include a 100 nF capacitor (using 3 x 47 nF is silly) and the resistive divider. As long as you do not have a very long Coax cable between this circuit and the SPDIF input, I expect this to work fine. Mine did anyway :-)

Comment: Yes, I think so too. The TORX179L will be mounted near RCA input, so the wire length will be very short.

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet suggests that the TORX device cannot drive a 430 ohm load (see the Abs Max Iout) though it's overall pretty vague (I can't see the specified load for the VOut specification). Whether you need 2 stages of inversion is another matter - the S/P-DIF format comes from AES/EBU which was designed to work equally well inverted or not.

So I believe you do need some sort of buffer stage of adequate bandwidth - well over 6 MHz to support 96kHz sample rate. @FakeMoustache says otherwise - perhaps he used a different optical receiver, or perhaps these work considerably better than the spec, but according to the datasheet, it isn't guaranteed.